# Windows phone 10 vpn pptp error 691

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have a Microsoft Lumia 950, OS build: 10.0.14393.67

Connecting to my work VPN using settings:

- VPN type: PPTP
- Type of sign-in info: Username and password

When clicking on Connect I get the error:

- The VPN connection failed with error code 691 - or
- The VPN connection failed with error code 812

both errors produce this warning and error in the VPN servers event log

Warning: The user --- connected from --- but failed an authentication attempt due to the following reason: The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error.

Error: The following error occurred in the Point to Point Protocol module on port: ---, UserName: ---. The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error.

What settings would I need to change in the RAS Server?

**EDIT:**

The issue only appears to affect Windows Mobile 10, as I can access the VPN successfully from my home computer. Also, the server the VPN is on is running Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Have you read http://serverfault.com/q/249558/126632 ? Have you done _any_ sort of troubleshooting at all?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Apologies, I should have mentioned that I **can** use the VPN from other machines, namely my personal computer at home. The issue only seems to appear on the Windows Mobile 10 platform.